# Excel - Index Match the oldest date that's non-zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel tables and I'm hoping to index match the oldest date that's non-zero in Column B, but I can't seem to come up with the excel formula. There are some blank dates and that's what's making it difficult because pulling the lowest value just pulls 0 (blank dates are listed as 0). Any help appreciated!

Table 1

| Name T1 | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Need Oldest Date |
| Carl | Need Oldest Date |
| John | Need Oldest Date |

Table 2

| Name T2 | Dates T2 |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 0 |
| Carl | 0 |
| John | 0 |
| Adam | 8/15/23 |
| Carl | 7/20/23 |
| John | 6/30/23 |
| Adam | 9/15/23 |
| Carl | 9/20/23 |
| John | 9/25/23 |
| Adam | 9/26/23 |
| Carl | 9/26/23 |
| John | 9/27/23 |

In the example above, I'm hoping to make a formula that in Column B will pull 8/15 for Adam, 7/20 for Carl and 6/30 for John, i.e. the oldest date only.

---

Goal:
Table 1

| Name T1 | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 8/15 |
| Carl | 7/20 |
| John | 6/30 |

index matching doesn't seem to work because it just pulls 0 as that is the first value for each person.

Comment: Use [`MAXIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel you can use MINIFS function to get the oldest dates

```
=MINIFS($H$3:$H$14,$G$3:$G$14,A3,$H$3:$H$14,"<>0")
```

[image]

---

Aggregate function works as well

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,Table2[Dates T2]/((Table2[Name T2]=[@[Name T1]])*(Table2[Dates T2]<>0)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think he means vote up, but I think new contributors can't vote up. @tempname5000 you should tick the `✓` left to the answer if you think this answer helped you best.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
    namet1, A2:A4,
    namet2, D2:D13,
    datest2, E2:E13,
    MAP(namet1, LAMBDA(m, TAKE(SORT(FILTER(datest2, (m = namet2) * datest2 <> 0)), 1)))
)
```

[image]